# What does this message means? How can I remove it?

Tags: discord.js

```
MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 message listeners added to [Client]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(Use node --trace-warnings ... to show where the warning was created)
```

Do you know how can I fix the situation?
Btw, a friend told me I should add a lot of commands in the same event... Do you think that would help? Thank you for your time :)

Comment: Have you tried what the error suggests? Logging it with `--trace-warnings`?

Comment: Oh guys i think you dont need to reply, I'm having help on top.gg server :3

Comment: They told me i can increase the max of event listeners...

Comment: But ty for your help!!

Comment: Of course you can. But the warning is there for a reason.

Comment: Yea that's true...

Comment: I will just increase it and if the warning keeps there I let you know ;)

Comment: OK I NOW REALIZED I ONLY NEED TO CREATE A LOT OF COMMANDS IN THE SAME EVENT

Comment: This warning usually means that you are listening to too many events in the same file, or your code simply cannot handle the events you currently have. Getting a proper event handler should fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error states that you have 11 `message` listeners open. You should only ever have 1 - since you can put all of your commands in the single message listener.

It would be helpful if you could post your `main.js` file content.

It should look like this:

```js
client.on("message", (message) => {
   if (message.content === "!examplecommand") {
      //command code here
   }
};
```

Please make sure you don't use 1 message event listener per command.

Comment: Yes I was talking to people in top.gg and I realized it, ty anyways Joe Moore